# How to enable specific plugin only based around shop manager role?

Tags: plugins, php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I have created a nice clutter free dashboard for the shop manager role which gives permissions to edit, maintain the store and hidden unnecessary junk i.e widgets, updates etc

The problem:

The current role side panel consists of:

**Dashboard

Blog

Media

Pages

Shop Manager** (Renamed from Woocommerce)
**Appearance**

I am using **ATUM Inventory manager** plugin for bulk edits, purchase order functionality etc. It's a great extension for managing stock.

Question:

With the current plugins menu hidden for this role, how do I enable a specific plugin only to appear on the side panel?

Comment: You will need to ask the plugin author. It depends on their implementation.